# MarkLogic java API join 2 documents

Tags: marklogic

Is there a way to join 2 documents within a marklogic database utilizing MarkLogic's Java API?

For instance let's say there's the following 2 documents:

doc1.xml:

```
<a>    
    <id>123</id>
    <doc2ID>111</doc2ID>
    <first_name>John</first_name>
</a>
```

doc2.xml:

```
<b>
    <id>111</id>
    <doc1ID>123</doc1ID>
    <last_name>Smith</last_name>
    <age>25</age>
</b>
```

Can i make the following query in MarkLogic:  retrieve all records where first name = John, last_name = Smith and age > 20 ?
In sql you would do something like this:
Select a.first_name, b.last_name from doc1 a JOIN doc2 b ON (a.doc2ID = b.id) WHERE a.first_name = 'John' and b.last_name = 'Smith' and b.age > 24

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use one document as a filter for another, you can send Query Options with a custom constraint that implements the subquery.

If you actually want to join documents, you would have to create a resource service extension that implements the join at the cts:search() level.

Stepping back, however, you should consider denormalizing your documents so you don't need to join as much as you would in a relational database.  The documents you provide above are, in essence, table rows, which does not take advantage of the power and flexibility of a document database.  Using relational models and relational queries is not the best approach in a document database.

Answer (score 0):

Your samples are not valid `xml` (no root element) and presumably there are more then one child elements. Without valid `xml` its hard to be precise in an answer.

The general way is you use a FLOWR expression:

```
for $master in doc("doc1.xml")//something,   
    $detail in doc("doc2.xml")//something 
where $master/doc2ID = $detail/id
return ($master/first_name/string(), $detail/last_name/string())
```

Comment: This looks like xquery that isn't available in the Java API only in Java XCC

Comment: XQuery is available in the Java Client API via resource extensions and now ServerEvaluationCall.